# Where is the link to the original question when a question is closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, user-interface

I've looked for how to remove the unity dock from my new installation and have found two answers that were closed as exact duplicates of previous questions.

What previous questions?

Please update the template so that if a question is closed as a duplicate, someone who finds it in a search is directed to the answer.

Comment: Please do not use caps as it conveys shouting. Also, as a future reference, changes in behavior of the W&A engine should be asked at [meta.SE] which is in the same network of sites.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ Can you link to anything approaching community consensus or network/moderator request that such questions belong only on Meta.SO?

Comment: @EliahKagan Pardon the overly-official way I stated it.  What I really *meant* to say is that they're more likely to be considered there since that's where most of the developers and site operators are/

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ That makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: wow, is there a question on Meta.SO that covers putting the duplicate text also in the "Closed" box since that is graphically the most prominent, people keep re-asking this question.

Answer (score 12):

Thank you for taking the time to post a suggestion. But this is already implemented!

[image: Duplicate box]

Answer (score 9):

When something is closed as a duplicate a header appears at the top of the post like:

> **Possible Duplicate:** link

That wouldn't stop somebody editing the post to remove it (maliciously or otherwise) but if you check the edit logs (click the "edited ..." link at the bottom of the post) you should be able to see what's happening.

If you still can't find it, please update your question with a link to the problem question and I'll try and track down what happened.

Comment: Great I had exact the same question and with this hint, I found the duplicated question and more important the answer which helped me.

Comment: Same here, I followed the trail and now I have the answer!