# 'closed as exact duplicate by...' is confusing - where is the answer?

Tags: bug, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the link to the original question when a question is closed as a duplicate?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2154/where-is-the-link-to-the-original-question-when-a-question-is-closed-as-a-duplic)

I find the 'closed as exact duplicate by...' message confusing.
Instead of telling me (the user) that question XYZ is a duplicated and listening the names of the people that marked the question as duplicate, I would like to see a **big button that link to the solution!**
Btw, I couldn't even find out how to open the *"original"* of a duplicated question after 30 sec (and I'm not a n00b).

For me the current implementation is a UX bug.

Comment: Check the top of the question, as exampled by this post, on where to find the duplicates.